# warning in the PageControl sample code: Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses

Tags: iphone, if-statement, warnings, conditional-statements, assignment-operator

I'm trying to understand the way UIPageControl works. SO I downloaded this sample code from Apple
[UIPageControlSampleCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)
It runs fine but there is a warning (Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses) at the if-statement in the following code:

```
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page 
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil])
    {
        pageNumber = page;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now my question is: why would the developer do something like this? making an assignment inside of an if-statement condition? Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assignment operator (=), except for performing the assignment, also returns the assigned value. This is so you can do stuff like

```
a = b = 1;
```

Which for the compiler is the same as writing

```
a = (b = 1);
```

This means that when doing

```
self = <some init function>;
```

You can check if the init succeeded by putting the assignment in an if statement. If it succeeded it returns a valid pointer, which is not zero which means the condition of the if statement is true. If the init fails, it returns nil which is actually zero, so there is no point in continuing the rest of the initialization.

The reason for the warning is that it's easy to accidentally use (=) in an if statement instead of (==):

```
if ( a = 1 ) // Should be a == 1
{
    // Do important stuff
}
```

So the compiler is trying to protect you from this mistake.

For this reason I prefer making the condition explicit, in your example:

```
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil]) != nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning is because since the sample code have been created by Apple, the version of the compiler and the default compiler options have changed.

Especially, this warning -- that tells you that you may mean "==" instead of "=" (because the statement is in a "if" condition and you generally test for equality instead of assignation) -- is quite logic; but **the warning wasn't activated by default in previous versions of the compiler and of Xcode**, which explains why such code may still be present in old sample codes *(nobody's perfect, even Apple developpers ;))*.

**The correct normal usage/convention is then**:

- Either to **explicitly test for equality** in the "if" condition, to be explicit to the compiler so that it is sure of what you mean: `if (nil != (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil]))`
- Or a notation that is also accepted by the compiler is to **double the parenthesis** to mention that making a condition with simple assignation and not "==" is not a mistake. Thus writing `if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil]))` will work too and remove the warning.

I would suggest to adopt the first solution.
If you explicitly test that, after the assignation, the result of the assignation (thus the value in `self`) is not nil, then when you read the code (even if it is not yours), you are sure of what was intended.

---

*Even if the code will work if you keep the code this way (and keep the warning), this warning ensures that you didn't mistype '=' instead of '==' in your code, as this may be a common mistake (for newbies but also for experienced programmers that may have typed too fast ;)) so I consider it being a good thing that it is now activated, and a good practice to explicitly make the comparison with nil for the sake of clarity*